# How can I automatically restore all sinon.js spies after each test in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, sinon

Is there some way I can find all active spies in sinon.js? I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
afterEach ->
  sinon.restoreAllSpies()

it "should not create a new MyClass", ->
  spy = sinon.spy(window, 'MyClass')
  expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Currently, I need to laboriously (and error-pronedly!) do this:

```
it "should not create a new MyClass", ->
  spy = sinon.spy(window, 'MyClass')
  expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
  window.MyClass.restore()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont think so, cause all it does is to replace the function with a spy, it dont save all spies internally. So ether you store all spies in an array and reset them on afterEach, or just create/override new spies on beforeEach.

Answer (score 18):

Answer found here: [Cleaning up sinon stubs easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552991/cleaning-up-sinon-stubs-easily)

Basically:

```
sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create()
sandbox.spy(object1, 'methodName')
sandbox.spy(object2, 'methodName')
sandbox.restore()
```