# Sinon.js- Trying to spy on console.log but it is already wrapped

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I am new to writing node tests.... this is a my first unit test for a gulp plugin I am trying to write:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var spy = require('chai-spies');
var es = require('event-stream');
var File = require('vinyl');
var mock = require('mock-fs');
var sinon = require('sinon');
var sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
//var rewire = require("rewire");
//var myModule = rewire("./test.js");
var es = require('event-stream');

chai.should();
chai.use(sinonChai);

describe('gulp-newy', function() {
  var fs = require('fs');
    var fakeFile, pspy;

    beforeEach(function() {
        //myModule.__set__('__dirname', "/home/one");
        mock({
            __dirname: mock.directory({
                mode: 0755,
                items: {
                file1: 'file one content',
                file2: new Buffer([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9])
                }
            })
        });

    });
    afterEach(mock.restore);


    describe('get files', function() {
        it('should do something', function(done) {
        mock({
            foo: mock.file({
            content: 'nothing',
            mtime: new Date(Date.now())
            }),
            bar: mock.file({
            content: 'nothing',
            mtime: new Date(1,1)
            })
        });
        fakeFile = new File({
           contents: new Buffer('foo'),
           history: ['foo']
        });


       var bar = function(dest) { return 'bar' };
       spy1 = sinon.spy(console, "log");
       stream = newy(bar);
       stream.write(fakeFile);
       stream.on('data', function() {
           console.log("sss");
       });
       spy1.should.have.been.called();
       done();
       });
    });
});
```

I get `TypeError: Attempted to wrap log which is already wrapped`, but I don't see where it was previously wrapped before my spy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using Mocha --watch...which session never ends. Because  of this.. the other spy existed. Answer is [Cleaning up sinon stubs easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552991/cleaning-up-sinon-stubs-easily)

Answer (score 3):

With sinon you need to make sure you restore your stubs\mocks after every test. if you don't they remain stubs and if you try and stub them again in a different test it will shout about trying to wrap a method again.
There are many ways to do this, contain all of the stubs within a sandbox, or just restore in the "after" clause.
for example:

```
describe('This is a test', ()=> {


       before(()=> {
            sinon.stub(myObject,'myMethod', ()=> {
                return 'stubbed result';
            })
        });
        it('should stub my method', ()=>{
            expect(myObject.myMethod).to.be.equal('stubbed result');
        });
        after(()=> {
            //important part
            myObject.myMethod.restore();
        });
    })
```