# Chai + Sinon error: method is already wrapped

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, sinon-chai

I am getting error:

- TypeError: Attempted to wrap ajax which is already wrapped
- Error: Stack Trace for original
  chai.should();

  ```
  describe("Test API", function() {

    it('executes a GET request for ISPs', function() {
      var mySpy = sinon.spy(jQuery, "ajax");
      sinon.stub(jQuery, 'ajax');
      mySpy.should.have.been.calledWithMatch({
      url: 'http://data-api.measurementlab.net/locations/nausdcwashington/clients'
      });
    });

    after(function() {
      jQuery.ajax.restore();
   });
  });
  ```

I came across similar posts and added the `after` block. Still getting the same error: [Sinon.js- Trying to spy on console.log but it is already wrapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053532/sinon-js-trying-to-spy-on-console-log-but-it-is-already-wrapped)

Answer (score 0):

is that the only place you're stubbing ajax? If not, you need to make sure you restore it after each test before trying to stub it again

Answer (score 0):

Why are you stubbing and spying jQuery.ajax? Remove this line: `sinon.stub(jQuery, 'ajax');`