# how do I use sinon sandboxes when tests run asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, sinon, stub

I've got some code I'm trying to test with a structure like this (per [Cleaning up sinon stubs easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552991/cleaning-up-sinon-stubs-easily)):

```
function test1() {
    // manually create and restore the sandbox
    var sandbox;
    beforeEach(function () {
        sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
        sandbox.stub(globalVar, "method", function() { return 1; });
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        sandbox.restore();
    });

    it('tests something', function(done) {
        anAsyncMethod(function() { doSomething(); done(); });
    }
 }
```

There is then a similar test2() function.

But if I do:

```
describe('two tests', function() {
    test1();
    test2();
}
```

I get:

```
TypeError: Attempted to wrap method which is already wrapped
```

I've done some logging to figure out the run order and it appears that the the issue is that it runs the test1 `beforeEach()` hook, then the test2 `beforeEach()` hook, then the test1 `it()`, etc.  Because it's calling the second `beforeEach()` before it gets to the `afterEach()` from the first test, we have a problem.

Is there a better way I should be structuring this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of your test spec should look something like this:

```
describe("A spec (with setup and tear-down)", function() {
  var sandbox;

  beforeEach(function() {
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
    sandbox.stub(globalVar, "method", function() { return 1; });
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it("should test1", function() {
    ...
  });

  it("should test2", function() {
    ...
  });
});
```

Or you could do this:

```
function test1() {
  ...
}

function test2() {
  ...
}

describe("A spec (with setup and tear-down)", function() {
  describe("test1", test1);
  describe("test2", test2);
});
```

Comment: But I'd like to be able to put these two specs in functions so I can reuse them for a variety of tests. And I'd like to have them be self contained so I don't have to create the sandbox and stubs code each time I call them. Is that not possible?

Comment: I see what you mean. Let me update my answer -- still new to formatting code in comments.

Comment: The extra describe wrapper - either as you have it or just inside each test function - does it. Extra tier of reporting, but as good as it appears is possible.  Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't help sinon not re-wrapping already wrapped methods when tests are async