# sinon: should restore mock stub manually?

Tags: javascript, sinon

My codes:

```
it('should delegate', sinon.test(function() {
  const stub = sinon.stub(this.Ext, 'process'); 
  // Question 1: should restore stub manually here? 
  // Question 2: what 'this' refer here?
}));
```

I am not sure whether the above code is OK or not. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552991/cleaning-up-sinon-stubs-easily), maybe the following two pieces of codes are better?

```
it('should restore all mocks stubs and spies between tests', function() {
  sinon.stub(some, 'method'); 
  // Question 3: How to restore all mocks stubs and spies between tests?
  // Question 4: what 'this' refer here?
}

it("should automatically restore all mocks stubs and spies", sinon.test(function() {
  this.stub(some, 'method'); 
  // Question 5: what 'this' refer here? test context?
}));
```

I am new to sinon. There are 5 questions in the above 3 pieces of codes. Any comments welcomed. Thanks